# Marshal code from Task.Run onto invoking thread

Tags: multithreading, .net-core

I am spinning up a network server with Socket's into a background process using `Task.Run`. I store the `Task` in a field within the server class so I can cancel it in the future if I need to. Once the `Task` has started I then boot up a game engine with state that runs synchronously.

```
private void ListenForConnection()
{
    this.listeningTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    this.listeningTask = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        while (!this.IsDeleted)
        {
            Socket clientSocket = await this.serverSocket.AcceptAsync();
            await this.CreatePlayerConnection(clientSocket);
        }
    }, this.listeningTokenSource.Token);
}

private async Task CreatePlayerConnection(Socket clientConnection)
{
    IServerConnection playerConnection = await this.connectionFactory.CreateConnection(clientConnection);
    IPlayer player = await this.playerFactory.CreatePlayer(playerConnection);
    if (playerConnection is TcpConnection tcpConnection)
    {
        tcpConnection.SetPlayer(player);
    }

    this.connectedPlayers.Add(player);
    await this.PlayerConnected(player);

    await player.ExecuteCommand(this.InitialCommand);
}
```

In this case, if a player connects to the server I pass the Socket into an `IServerConnection` instance and assign it to the player. As client commands are sent across the socket, the `IServerConnection` for that client receives it parses it and then somewhere in the pipeline it will want to modify game state outside of that `IServerConnection`; by interacting with entities running within the engine (possible even on another thread themselves).

This all happens in a `netcoreapp2.0` console app.

Will I run into issues with the client socket originating from the background operation, when it goes to touch state that is in a different thread? In WPF and aspnet I've used SynchronizationContext's in the past but console apps don't have this.

What is a clean way to make sure I don't deadlock everywhere, without having to litter locks all over the place. Can I capture the current thread before starting the `ListenForConnection()` Task and marshal state changes back onto that original thread?

Comment: From what i understand it is not a `socket` problem but a common-resource one.In your case that would the game engine which would get changed by different threads.If multiple clients will change a common resource , i would wrap my engine/common resource in an object and use a lock inside that wrapper whenever the value gets changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my perspective you will always end up with a common resource that will get updated by different threads.So using a `lock` is the way to go.However if you wrap your resource and your lock and in an object you can keep all `synchronization` operations locally.

```
public class Resource{
    public int Value{get;set;}
}

public class Engine
{
   private Resource commonResource=new Resource();
   private object @lock=new object();
   public void  ChangeResource(int newvalue)
   {
      lock(@lock)
      {
        this.commonResource.Value=newvalue;
      }
   }
}
public class Client{
    private Engine engine;
    public Client(Engine engine)
    {
        this.engine=engine;
    }
    public void ChangeResource(int newValue){
        this.engine.ChangeResource(newvalue);
    }
}
```

**P.S** I do not know how you use your Engine/wrapper(whatever it is that you said the clients make changes on) so i just injected it in all clients.You could use a `singleton` also.
If you run `async` operations consider using a [SempahoreSlim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim?view=netframework-4.7.2) instead of lock.

Comment: In your example, it would be more like the `Client` instance telling the properties in the `Engine` to do things. For example `foreach(IPlayer player in Engine.Players) { player.World.Zone.SetTime(newTime); }`. I would have to `lock` on the properties that my call to the `Zone` interacts with right? This pattern is kind of common in my code-base and would require me locking almost all properties on my entities. I was thinking instead publishing to a bus from the client. Something like `bus.Publish(new ChangeZoneTimeMessage(newTime))`. The bus would force it to the main thread.

Comment: Well if you lets say create a bus that all clients would publish changes, and from this bus the thread with the `engine` would `dequeue` and apply the changes, then you would still have to make the `bus` thread-safe .Indeed you would just need to lock the bus and not the properties.

Comment: Ok. Sounds like I need to do some rearchitecting. My engine doesn’t have a game loop (it’s all event driven) that can be used to poll for new messages in the bus. Eventing in a multi-threaded scenario probably isn’t what I want in this case. Thanks

Comment: I have implemented once a `Reactive`  Queue, that as you say would get events , and consumers would subscribe to it.Maybe it could help you : [source](https://github.com/sanzor/RQueue)